# Volume of List3DPlot with no function for ImplicitRegion

Tags: mathematica-online

I have simulated a 3D plot for the crater created using laser ablation.
This was created using an imported excel file into mathematical.

I have tried studying ImplicitRegion. However, it requires a specific function. I am not sure about the particular equation governing the graph.

[image]

This is my code (which is messy) for the 3d plot used in the graph.

```
data = Import[
    "/3dplot_gaus.xlsx"][[1]];

dims = Dimensions[data];
xd = Transpose[data][[1]][[2 ;; dims[[1]]]];
(*data[[2;;,1]]; *)(*First column = x-axis*)
yd = data[[1]][[2 ;; dims[[2]]]];
(*data[[1,2;;]]; *)(*First row=y-axis*)
zd = data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];  (*z-axis = depth*)

plotdata = Take[data, -dims[[1]] + 1, -dims[[2]] + 1];

ListPlot3D[plotdata, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 DataRange -> {{First[xd], Last[yd]}, {First[xd], Last[yd]}, 
   Automatic},(*AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},*)BoundaryStyle -> Automatic, 
 Filling -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x-axis (m)", None, Rotate["depth (m)", 1.55]}, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, 
   11],(*AxesLabel->{Style["x-axis",Black],None,Style["depth \
(m)",Black]},*)(*PlotLabel->"Gaussian Beam (\[Lambda]=800 \
nm)",*)(*Mesh->All,*)
 Ticks -> {{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, None, Automatic}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 11], 
 PlotTheme -> {"ZMesh"},(*Boxed->False,*)
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", "Reverse"}][
     Rescale[#3, {-1.0385*10^(-7), 0.}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

I hope you can help me. I've been at this problem for 2 weeks now.

Comment: Please post example data.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an interpolation function of your data and integrate it to get the volume.

Here's a simpler example, using created data of a hole and zero values around the hole:

```
plotdata = Flatten[
  Table[{{x, y}, -Exp[-x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 0.2}],
  1];
interp = Interpolation[plotdata];
Integrate[interp[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

which gives -3.11247. The volume is the absolute value of this integral.

You can check the data with a plot:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten /@ plotdata, PlotTheme -> "ZMesh"]
```